# cannot find method prepareStatement(String)

Tags: java, mysql

I'm currently working on my first java project and I need some help. I want to make a login form an connect my program with a sql database. I followed some tutorials on youtube but I can't figure out why I still have an error. Here is my code:

```
 private void jButton_LoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String username = jTextField_Username.getText();
    String password = String.valueOf(jPassword_Pass.getPassword());
    
    ResultSet rs;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    
    String query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`= ? AND `password`= ?";
    
    //check if the fields are empty
    if(username.trim().equals("") || password.trim().equals(""))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter The Username & Password", "Empty Fields", 2);
    }
    
    else 
    {
        ps = DB.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
    }

}
```

My program doesn't work correctly because I have the error "cannot find method prepareStatement(String), location: class Object" at the line "ps = DB.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);"
Please help me. I use NetBeans 12.4

Comment: What is the return type of the `getConnection()` method? Make sure it's `java.sql.Connection` and not, for instance, `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: Are you *sure* that's the error? btw, the time to trim the strings is when you get them from the fields. You need to set the query parameters of course

Comment: *I followed some tutorials on youtube* - why use youtube videos? You can't copy/paste the example code. Search this site for examples that use `PreparedStatement`. Then you can easily copy/paste/modify/test the code. The code you posted definitely won't work because you never set the value of the variables for the PreparedStatement. Also, this question has nothing to do with Swing. This is an SQL issue.

Comment: Thank you all! I think @Slaw is right, my getConnection() method returns java.lang.Object. I try to figure out how to make my progam to return java.sql.Connection type

Comment: Simply change the method definition from `public Object getConnection() { ... }` to `public Connection getConnection() { ... }` (and import `java.sql.Connection` if not already).

Comment: I rewrite the code and still doesn't work. Even if I wrote public Connection getConnection() { ... } , I still have that horrible error :(